# If $y=e^x(3\sin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})+2\cos(\sqrt{3}x))$, then the sixth derivative of y with respect to x at x=0 is?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I know that there is an obvious and tedious way to differentiate it 6 times and then find out the answer but since I have to find the sixth derivative at x=0, I was looking for a short method(Yes, there is surely a method).

I could not find a way to group the trigonometric functions which could make the job easier.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule you can just use this "binomial theorem" for the product rule

Comment: Expand it using Taylor series, then take a look at the coefficient of $x^6$.

Comment: Can you please provide the steps, I have not yet learnt expansions at depth.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Taylor expansions at $0$. We need the sixth order for $e^x$ and the the trigonometric sum.

$$b(x)=e^x=1+x+{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over 6}+{x^4\over 24}+{x^5\over 120}+{x^6\over 720}+o(x^6)\\
c(x)=3\sin{x\over\sqrt{3}}+2\cos{\sqrt{3}x}=2+3{x\over\sqrt{3}}-{3x^2}-{x^3\over 6\sqrt{3}}+{3x^4\over 4}+{x^5\over 360\sqrt{3}}-{3x^6\over 40}+o(x^6)\\
$$

We’re interested in the coeffficient of $x^6$ because we know that $a_6=f^{(6)}(0)/6!$ and the coefficient of $x^6$ is

$$a_6=b_1c_5+b_2c_4+b_3c_3+b_4c_2+b_5c_1$$

And surprise surprise one gets $a_6$=0

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $\sin(\theta)=\Im{(e^{i\theta})}$, $\cos(\theta)=\Re{(e^{i\theta})}$, and $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{\alpha x} = \alpha^n e^{\alpha x}$.